# View/Stream list of images from s3 in ionic

Tags: angularjs, image, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, lazy-loading

We would want to transfer the hosting of the images uploaded via mobile into AWS S3(Images are not publicly viewed) instead of the server local storage. The challenge is that, how to view/stream the images in the most efficient way and limiting the memory consumption of the mobile phone since we will be sending request to AWS S3 server to give as the file url.

In the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property), we can view the image url via s3.getSignedUrl and which will have a response of the secured url.

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
    Bucket: 'myBucket',
    Key: 'mypath/image.jpg'
  };

s3.getSignedUrl ('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
      console.log(url);
  });
```

In ionic mobile app, we were using [image-lazy-src](https://github.com/paveisistemas/ionic-image-lazy-load) to efficiently load the images without waiting for the others to load. Now the challenge is how to implement the lazy load for S3. I was thinking to create a directive which downloaded/requested the image url from s3 then use the image-lazy-src to load the images. I dont know if this is an advisable way to do since you will be sending consecutive N number of request to S3 depends on the number of images you have in your list.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find a temporary solution or alternative. We edited the directive image-lazy-src and created a new one with S3 first to download the aws url and then load it to image-lazy-src image loader.

```
var s3_url;
 if ($scope.imageLazyBackgroundImage == "true") {  

  var bgImg = new Image();
  bgImg.onload = function () {
      if ($attributes.imageLazyLoader) {
          loader.remove();
      }
      $element[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + s3_url + ')'; // set style attribute on element (it will load image)
      if ($scope.lazyScrollResize == "true") {
          //Call the resize to recalculate the size of the screen
          $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
      }
  };

  bgImg.src =  s3_url;


  } else {
    //Download the aws image url and then assign it to the created image
    AwsService.generateAwsUrl('test').then(function(url){
      s3_url= url;
      $element[0].src = s3_url;// set src attribute on element (it will load image)
    },function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }
 }
```